# exporting PATH not working in a bash shell on linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

For example, I type to the following command:

```
         # PATH=$PATH:/var/test
         # echo $PATH
           ........./var/test       // working
         # export PATH
```

Next, I open another bash shell session to test if the export works by typing the following command:

```
         # echo $PATH
          ........      // not working as in I don't see /var/test path
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you have set the `PATH` environment variable only for your current `bash` session. You need to add the line `PATH=$PATH:/var/test` into `~/.bashrc` so that it works for any `bash` shell.

Just run the following command to put it into your `rc`(run commands) file (rc files contain startup information for a command(initialization)):
`echo "PATH=$PATH:/var/test" >> ~/.bashrc`

More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_commands
https://superuser.com/questions/789448/choosing-between-bashrc-profile-bash-profile-etc

`export`ing a variable makes it available only in child processes spwaned/started from that bash shell.
As an example:

```
$ export var=abcd
$ sh
$ echo "$var"
abcd
$ exit
$ echo "$var"
abcd
$
```

`sh` is the child process of `bash` hence it gets the value of `var`, since you open a new `bash` which is a different process altogether it does get the `PATH` value.

Comment: I thought the purpose of export is to make it available in all shells, right?

Comment: `export` is used to make it available in subsequent child shells

Comment: thanks for clearing up my misunderstanding of export

Comment: I use a system wide bashrc in /etc/profile.local that is not being sourced in a bash script.  This method may work better if you need to do this across many users or access custom configuration items inside a login script that you don't control.  Since /etc/profile.local is a login only script that gets sourced, you have to call your script with #!/bin/bash -l to source that, however this will make scripts inside find commands run slower.